# `body` parameter is absent in AWS Lambda Authorizer `event` object

Tags: aws-lambda

The event object is missing `body` and `isBase64Encoded` properties. But they should be there according to the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#set-up-lambda-proxy-integration-using-cli) The full structure is the following:

```
{
    "type": "REQUEST",
    "methodArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-west-2:*******:*******/development/POST/auth/login",
    "resource": "/{proxy+}",
    "path": "/auth/login",
    "httpMethod": "ANY",
    "headers": {
       .....
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {
        "test": "123"
    },
    "pathParameters": {
        "proxy": "auth/login"
    },
    "stageVariables": {
        "lambdaVersion": "development"
    },
    "requestContext": {
        "path": "/development/auth/login",
        "accountId": "*****",
        "resourceId": "f8wvnk",
        "stage": "development",
        "requestId": "****",
        "identity": {
            ....
        },
        "resourcePath": "/{proxy+}",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "apiId": "********"
    }
}
```

Does anyone have the similar issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In custom authorizer request type there is no body in the passed event to the authorizer. According to the documentation:

> For a custom authorizer of the REQUEST type, API Gateway passes the required request parameters to the authorizer Lambda function as part of the event object. The affected request parameters include headers, path parameters, query string parameters, stage variables, and some of request context variables.

NO Body is there!

Comment: You are right. I checked wrong docs (for Lambda proxy integration). Here are the [correct ones](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/use-custom-authorizer.html) and there is no `body` and `isBase64Encoded` params there. So there is no any way to get request body within Authrozer Lambda, correct?

Answer (score 1):

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/

> Enhanced request authorizer Lambda functions receive an event object
>   that is similar to proxy integrations. It contains all of the
>   information about a request, excluding the body.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced request authorizer Lambda functions receive an event object that is similar to proxy integrations. It contains all of the information about a request, excluding the body.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).